# Making a collapsible tableview(dropdown function) using static tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I've seen multiple tutorials using dynamic tableview to make a collapsible tableview (aka dropdown functionality). However, I could not see any tutorial utilizing a static tableview. I particularly want to use a static tableview because I do not need to use data source at all.

In below image, I set "disclosure indicator" as accessory type on cell "part 2". Is there I can manually manipulate in the storyboard using a static tableview?

[image]

If not, can you suggest me a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can override the delegate methods to return a different number of rows but it's not pretty or safe.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, is there other way I can achieve? Or do I just need to use a dynamic tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You can override didSelecRowAtIndexPath to determine which row do what.

For example:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        print("row 0")
    }
    else {

        print("other row")
    }
}
```

Hope this help.